# Django ElasticSearch DSL partial matching using nGram analyzer

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm quite new to the ElasticSearch topic and I'm trying to implement simple e-commerce search in my Django application using ElasticSearch with library `django-elasticsearch-dsl` [Github repo](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl) .

The thing I'm trying (extremely simplified) to achieve is that, considering these Django model instances:

```
Red T-shirts
Blue T-Shirts
Nice T-Shirts
```

for search term `T-Sh` I'll obtain all these three results:

```
Red T-shirts
Blue T-Shirts
Nice T-Shirts
```

So I have this model in *shop/models.py* (again very simplified)

```
class Category(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
   # In reality here I have more fields
   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

With *shop/documents.py*

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

autocomplete_analyzer = analyzer('autocomplete_analyzer',
            tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'nGram', min_gram=1, max_gram=20),
            filter=['lowercase']
        )from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

@registry.register_document
class CategoryDocument(Document):

    title: fields.TextField(analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer, search_analyzer='standard') # Here I'm trying to use the analyzer specified above


    class Index:
        name = 'categories'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
            'max_ngram_diff': 20 # This seems to be important due to the constraint for max_ngram_diff beeing 1
        }

    class Django:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'title', 
            # In reality here I have more fields
        ]
```

And finally, my *shop/views.py*

```
class CategoryElasticSearch(ListView):
    def get(self, request, lang):
        search_term = request.GET.get('search_term', '')
        q = Q(
            "multi_match", 
            query=search_term,
            fields=[
                'title', 
                # In reality here I have more fields
                ], 
            fuzziness='auto',)
        search = search.query(q)
        # ... etc
```

But result for `T-Sh` is empty. I get something only when writing something longer such as `T-Shir`. Now I'd probably obtain all three results.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Omg I made it working.

For anyone dealing with this - analyzers are defined on each "field" in the mapping. In other words, in order to attach analyzer to the `title` field our *shop/documents.py* has to look like this:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

autocomplete_analyzer = analyzer('autocomplete_analyzer',
            tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'nGram', min_gram=1, max_gram=20),
            filter=['lowercase']
        )from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

@registry.register_document
class CategoryDocument(Document):

    #title: fields.TextField(analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer, search_analyzer='standard') # Here I'm trying to use the analyzer specified above <-- This was extremely incorrect, due to the colon in definition, I don't know how I missed it but I did...
     title = fields.TextField(required=True, analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer) # This is it....

    class Index:
        name = 'categories'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
            'max_ngram_diff': 20 # This seems to be important due to the constraint for max_ngram_diff beeing 1
        }

    class Django:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            # 'title' <-- Notice, I removed this field, it would be redeclaration error
            # In reality here I have more fields
        ]
```

And it works flawlessly...

Comment: Thanks for the help with this! A tip on `min_gram` and `max_gram` [from the elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_14), that might be helpful: _It usually makes sense to set min_gram and max_gram to the same value. The smaller the length, the more documents will match but the lower the quality of the matches. The longer the length, the more specific the matches. A tri-gram (length 3) is a good place to start._

Answer (score 0):

I turned off `fuzziness='auto'`, because on large volumes, getting the result of the request slowed down significantly.

[Here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7069988804652056576/) is the reference where I found this soltion that helped me.